# Chiral constraint on superfield

Tags: supersymmetry, superspace-formalism

In SUSY to select the required supermultiplet from the entire set of fields in the general superfield we must impose the follow constraint

$\bar{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}\Phi=0$

And a superfield subject to this condition is called chiral superfield. Usually, to solve this equation, new coordinates are introduced

$y^{\mu}=x^{\mu}+i\bar{\theta}\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}\theta$

Then it is solved automatically. My question is the following - is it possible to solve the equation above without introducing new coordinates? Maybe use some analogue of the method of characteristics or something else? Let's say I could not come up with a new coordinates above - what should I do in this case to solve the equation?